# Parsing nested lists (lisp s-expressions) with gson

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to (de)serialize a list of conditions which can be connected by AND/OR via gson.

`class Condition {
  String property; 
  String operator;
  String value;
}`

Can anyone think of an easy way of parsing "lisp s-expression"-like arrays with gson and storing them into a java object?

`class MyObject {
  List<Condition> conditions; 
}`

Problem: there are AND / OR relations between those conditions, as shown below.

**Examples**:

Implicit AND:
`[condition1, condition2, condition3]`

Explicit AND:
`["AND", condition1, condition2, condition3]`

Both expressions are semantically equivalent to *(condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3)*

Implicit AND/OR:
`[condition1, condition2, ["OR", condition3, condition4]]`

Explicit AND/OR:
`["AND", condition1, condition2, ["OR", condition3, condition4]]`

Both expressions are semantically equivalent to *(condition1 AND condition2 AND (condition3 OR condition4))*

Probably a tree-like data type could store the parsed result?
Does anyone could suggest a better way of transporting and storing AND/OR conditions

Thanks

Comment: I am limited to Java7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be appropriate to parse this json not into your own class, but into `JsonElement` class which already exists in Gson and abstract enough for your kind of task (in fact it's a tree already).

```
JsonElement ast = new JsonParser().parse(json);
```

You can check whether it's an array by calling `ast.isJsonArray()` or get string value using `ast.getAsString()`

It might be not the best solution but I think it's reasonable to reuse already existing API if it suits your needs